# getChildView called multiple times using gridview on Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-gridview, expandablelistadapter

I have 2 groups of data that comes from an API, each of them have 7 objects which I'm trying to display in a gridview, so I have an expandable listview with 2 groups with 7 objects for each one. The problem is, when I run the app the 2 groups is showing the same array of data that is the last one, so the 2 groups is printing the same 7 objects of group two. Running the log I saw that the getChildView is called multiple times, I'm new to android development, I don't know why this is happening. Can someone help me?

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Group> groups;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Child>> child = new ArrayList();

    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
        child = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {
            child.add(i, groups.get(i).getItems());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return child.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview, null);
        }
        CustomGridView gridView = (CustomGridView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.GridView_toolbar);

        for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {

            ArrayList<String> listchild = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int j = 0; j < groups.get(i).getItems().size(); j++) {

                listchild.add(child.get(i).get(j).getName());

            }
            gridView.setExpanded(true);
            GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(context, listchild);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);// Adapter
        }

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        tv.setText(group.getName());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what I needed, that way I get all the items from its respective groups:

```
  @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview, null);
        }
        CustomGridView gridView = (CustomGridView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.GridView_toolbar);


            listchild = new ArrayList<Child>();

            for(int j = 0; j< groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().size(); j++) {

                listchild.add(child.get(groupPosition).get(j));

            }

            gridView.setExpanded(true);
            GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(context, listchild);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);// Adapter


        return convertView;

    }
            gridView.setExpanded(true);
            GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(context, listchild);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);// Adapter
```

Answer (score 3):

getChildView will be called depending on the number of items each of your groups
has. So, if your groups has a size of 2 and each group of groups has 7 items then there should be a total of 14 calls. Your getChildrenCount function should look like this:

```
public int getChildrenCount(int nGroup)
{
  return groups.get(nGroup).size();
}
```

Your getChildView should also have a checking as to which group, int groupPosition, is currently processed.

Like

```
  public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int nChild, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    try
    {
      if (groupPosition == 0)
      {
        ...
        ... your code here
      }
    }
    ...
  }
```

Comment: it will be called depending on the number of child views you have. So, if  you have 10 child views, the code will be called 10 times.

Comment: make getChildrenCount returns 1.